# What do you call a person that helps buy things?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

Let's say there's a school club. There's a person in charge of ordering/buying things for the club. What would you call this person's role?

Comment: Did you look up buyer?  Purchaser, purchasing agent (in a larger organization).

Comment: Consider bursar - https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/bursar - this may be specific to BrEng though.

Comment: @MaxWilliams - In the US "bursar" is generally taken to mean "head accountant", and it's use is limited to colleges and similar institutions.

Answer (score 5):

Most clubs that I've known assigned such a role to the person responsible for the funds, so "treasurer" is quite common.

"Purchaser" and "buyer" are another clear approach. I've only seen these as roles in a business context, but a club certainly could use the terms and be clearly understood.

Comment: treasurer is most often used for clubs, as they look after the money coming in and going out, so nothing would get bought without them.

Comment: +1 for Purchaser. Also Purchasing Agent. Both typically used when referring to a business, though, not a club.

Comment: You know what? I'll add that.

Answer (score 4):

For clubs or societies, you should research the role of the **quartermaster**.  This might come closest to the duties and responsibilities you describe.  Also used widely in organisations like scouts and guides.

Ref e.g. 
https://meritbadge.org/wiki/index.php/Quartermaster

Comment: Quartermaster is a cool word, and the origin of the codename Q, for the person who supplies James Bond with cars and gadgets.  I don't know if they usually do the actual buying though.

Comment: "Quartermaster" is usually used in a military context.

Comment: It's true that it's used most often in a military context, but it fits beautifully.

Answer (score -2):

A person that helps to buy things could be "**an advisor**".